# Python crontab module

Tags: python

I'm trying to run File.py script on Windows with module python cron tab. I have this code and it does not work.

```
tab = CronTab(tab="""
  */1 * * * * C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\File.py
  """)

cmd = 'C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\File.py'

# You can even set a comment for this command
cron_job = tab.new(cmd)
cron_job.minute.every(1)
```

Can anyone correct please my example or how can I call this File.py correctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250365/crontab-fails-to-execute-python-script

Comment: This is not the same thing. Im using python crontab on windows system.

Comment: Please explain /how/ it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

python-crontab only works on Linux/Unix machines because windows doesn't have a crontab service component. It is possible to edit crontab files on windows, but it doesn't provide any scheduling services itself.

You should look for a python scheduler service which will continue to run in the background.