# Python script error with cron

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a python script every hour with cron.
This is everything I have in my crontab.

```
0 * * * * python /Users/jamesrusso/Documents/TorMeasure/TorMeasurementProject/getConsensus.py
```

But I get an error when it tries to run saying `ImportError: No module named stem.descriptor`. I have included `#!/usr/local/bin/python` in my python script. Does anyone know a way to fix this or need more info let me know

Comment: What do you get when you type `python --version`? Is it the same as `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Comment: it doesn't matter you have `#!/usr/local/bin/python` in script because you run `python script`. Use full path to Python in crontab.

Comment: its always better to use `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: have you tested your script before inserting to cronjob, is ti was working fine?

Comment: python version gives me "Python 2.7.10"  which is the same as when i use /usr/local/bin/python. Yes it works fine in terminal. What do you mean #!/usr/bin/env python is better? Should I put that in the python script

Comment: @Hackaholic: there can be security issues using `env` and `$PATH`.  Some sites ban its use.

Comment: Since you don't appear to have multiple copies of Python, this issue might be an environment variable like `PYTHONPATH`.  Many of the issues with cron are because the startup files, like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, are not executed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250365/crontab-fails-to-execute-python-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have multiple Python versions installed in your machine. Change your cron line to include the full path:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /Users/jamesrusso/Documents/TorMeasure/TorMeasurementProject/getConsensus.py
```

Comment: I feel like this might be the problem, will keep you posted when the script runs in 14 mins

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you can check:

## Step 1:

```
$which python 
will give you location of python installed
```

## step 2:

```
try to include 
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## step 3:

```
you can give the full path of python in your cronjob
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /Users/jamesrusso/Documents/TorMeasure/TorMeasurementProject/getConsensus.py
```

## step 4:

```
have you tested your script before inserting to cronjob, is it was working fine?
```