# Scheduling cronjob using python cannot find module bs4

Tags: python, cron, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script to scrape some web data that I would like to run every 10 minutes. The script runs fine when I do it from the command line but I get an error when I try to run it using a cronjob every 10 minutes because it can't import bs4'. I get this error:

```
No module named bs4
```

My crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages python /Users/{username}/Documents/scripts/cot.py
```

I got the PYTHONPATH variable by finding where 'bs4' was downloaded using this command:

```
python -c 'import bs4; print(bs4.__file__)'
```

Output in /var/{username}/mail:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME={username}>
X-Cron-Env: <USER={username}>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/{username}>
Message-Id: <20171223194001.0783F8639E1@mbp-0500.localdomain>
Date: Sat, 23 Dec 2017 13:40:00 -0600 (CST)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/{username}/Documents/scripts/cot.py", line 3, in <module>
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Comment: Why not run the `.py` in the cron instaed ? `python /route/to/script.py`

Comment: i thought that's what I'm doing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, did you try running it using just `python` without the full path ? if it works in the command line it should work @ cron. Also, you didn't install `BeautifulSoup` in a virtualenv, right ?

Comment: yeah I can run it in terminal using python and then the path.  Not in a virtualenv.

Comment: print `sys.path` to see what paths `python` uses to find modules - ie. `import sys ; print('\n'.join(sys.path))`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case the job was executed by root and not in user mode. Be sure to execute the cronjob in user mode. The right solution was answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388939/1864498)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with bs4 and python.

I eventually solved it by creating a shell script (making it executable with `chmod +x`) then executing that script from the command line (`./scraper.sh`)

bs4 was installed but it threw an error so I downloaded it again with pip using the --user flag (`pip3 install bs4 --user`), and it worked fine.

Then I set the crontab to run the shell script (I think running it as a shell script preserves some of the environmental variables that python or conda needs, read that in a different question)

Hope this helps!